# How to make an element grow when hovered on. Through the use of javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I want to program a certain effect that makes an element 'grow' larger, when you hover your mouse over it. It loses its added class after you leave the element.  But i can't make it work.

What i've got so far:

```js
$("container").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
);
```

```css
#scrollist {
  background: #808080;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}
#scrlist {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
}
.active {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: height .19s, width .16s;
  -moz-transition: height .19s, width .16s;
  -o-transition: height .19s, width .16s;
  -ms-transition: height .19s, width .16s;
  transition: height .19s, width .16s;
}
.active:hover {
  width: 240px;
  height: 350px;
}
.n1 {
  width: 240px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollist">
  <ul id="scrlist">
    <li>
      <a href="/" class="container" id="cont1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/" class="container" id="cont2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/" class="container n1" id="cont3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/" class="container" id="cont4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/" class="container" id="cont5"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What “certain effect”?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply toggle the class **.active** as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".container").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

[See demo example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcx8hdyx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouseover instead of hover and add dots before container. This should work:

```
$(function(){
  $(".container").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");        
  });
  $(".container").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active");        
  });
});
```